# What is a modern C++ approach to structures containing symbolic constants?

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
enum bool
{
    FALSE = 0,
    TRUE = 1
};
```

I'm wondering how to translate this in a modern C++ approach and if there is a well suited container for that; i know that the `enum` are not really that appreciated, but i can't think about a real alternative in the C++ world.

What if would like to associate the execution of a particular method with a state?

---

Ok, this is the part where i will be more verbose.

I would like to stress the fact that i'm asking about structures symbolic constants and not about TRUE and FALSE, i'm not that "needy".

Suppose that i have a structure that can represent several states with their own constants

```
enum semaphore
{
    GREEN = 0,
    ORANGE = 1,
    RED = 2
};
```

this is C code, now my question is about how to do the same in C++ if there is a better way.

My question continue when i ask about the possibility to do something like an automatic triggering when a change of state will occur, for example:

```
int main
{
   ...
   semaphore = 1;
   ...
}
```

and without any extra statements this has to trigger a `method()` just because the semaphore is now orange.

I hope that is more clear now.

Comment: Like chris said, in C++11 we have `enum class` for that (well, for that particular problem we obviously have `bool`). Of course it also depends on what your actual needs are (that is, do you just want to introduce a few somewhat related names? Or do they have more complex relationships?)

Comment: `enum struct` is also scoped.

Comment: @Cubic no, i mean all the possible approach with symbolic constants; if someone can drop some lines as examples this would be appreciated, especially for the part related to the methods.

Comment: Please, explain what do you want to achieve, even with a bad syntax.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? I can't quite extrapolate it from the example. `true` and `false` are actually keywords in C++, so the example may not be the most representative.

Comment: OP discusses C++, but tagged his question C. Deleting C tag.

Comment: Ok, so your original question has absolutely nothing to do with your edit.

Comment: @Ken: it's generally not a good idea to modify a question so radically that it invalidates existing answers. Like you just did.

Comment: "*without any extra statements this has to trigger a method()*" When does this "triggering" happen? Upon assignment of the value?

Comment: -1: Unclear question that still requires questions in comments after updating.

Comment: @NicolBolas i still think that both versions are the same question, probably i gave the wrong example, but anyway the triggering is supposed to happen when the state change, i suppose we can use the = operator as reference, but speaking in general terms just when the change happens.

Comment: @KirillKobelev can you at least specify what part of the question you don't get?

Comment: Why do you think you cannot continue using your old approach in C++? Was it ok for you in C? Why?

Comment: @KirillKobelev i was asking for something modern, i have never said that this approach is old or it doesn't works, by the way in the C++ 11 there is something new about enum, i just found out that http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html so asking this question is not that weird, there is something going on and a much modern approach

Comment: Still not fully clear. Removing -1, trying to answer.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a C++ property - something that triggers a method call when it's assigned to or evaluated/read-from.  If that's the case, the symbolic constant part of the question really has little to do with the question (much less being the main part of the question).

Comment: @MichaelBurr can you write an answer with your example in it as code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What if would like to associate the execution of a particular method with a state?*

I'm not sure I get your point, but maybe you mean something like this:

**DEFINITION**

Instead of this:

```
enum BOOL
{
  FALSE = 0,
  TRUE = 1
};

void executeOnlyWithTrue(BOOL b)
{
  if (b == TRUE)
  {
    RunParticularMethodOnlyNeededForTrueState();
  }
}
```

You do this:

```
class BOOL
{
public:
  virtual void  executeOnlyWithTrue() const {/*default does nothing*/} 
};

class FALSE : public BOOL
{  //no override, so using default executeOnlyWithTrue (BOOL's) 
};

class TRUE : public BOOL
{
public:
  virtual void  executeOnlyWithTrue() const
  {
    RunParticularMethodOnlyNeededForTrueState();
  }
};
```

**USAGE**

Instead of this:

```
const BOOL b = TRUE;
...
executeOnlyWithTrue(b)
...
```

You do this:

```
const BOOL& b = TRUE();
b.executeOnlyWithTrue();
```

Comment: this is an idea but it's not really what i'm looking for, i want the call for the method to be "transparent" and automatic when the change of state occur.

Comment: you can make a Semaphore class and overload assignment operator ? so `Semaphore semaphore; semaphore = 1;` can do custom stuffs?

Comment: yes I can do that, it's a code that i'm writing from the ground up

Comment: hm. What about having a copy of the data in the memory, and running a separate thread that periodically checks the value of the variable? Of course, in a thread-safe manner. I think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If `semaphore` is of class type, then the assignment:

```
semaphore = 5;
```

will automatically call function `semaphore.operator=(int)` if it exists. Thus you can monitor any "changes" of `semaphore` by implementing this function (it need not change anything but such might violate the principle of least surprise).

Comment: so you mean an overloading for the operator **=**